# Does increasing my attack increase the attack of my djinni?

Tags: golden-sun-dark-dawn

If I use a djinn or a psynergy move that increases my attack, does it also increase attacks of summoned creatures and djinni? Or is it just my party's weapon attacks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Djinn's (and their summons') attack strength is increased by the Elemental Power of that element (e.g. Venus Power) or elements, since they do elemental damage.

You get +5 Power per Djinni set, you can gain more Elemental Power by summoning or equipping certain items that increase elemental power.

To learn more about Elemental Power, consult your local [Golden Sun Wiki](http://goldensunwiki.net/Elemental_Power)